# SQLite Database: second table will not add new products

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm doing a project where I have two tables one stores the users of the app and the other stores the products entered by the user. the user table is working fine however when I looked by at my logcat I'm finding that no products are being entered into the product table. There were no errors with the addproduct method in the database handler so I'm wondering what am I doing wrong? Is the problem in the databasehandler or in the way i am adding my Products? Any help would be really appreciated?
Database handler code:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import com.example.john.fitnessapp.Products;
import com.example.john.fitnessapp.Users;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TAG = "DBHelper";
    //DATABASE VERSION
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    //DATABASE NAME
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AppDatabase";
    //TABLE NAMES
    private static final String TABLE_USERS = "Users_Table";
    private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "Products_Table";
    //COMMON COLUMN NAMES
    private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "User_ID";
    private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_ID = "Product_ID";
    //USER TABLE
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "Username";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";
    private static final String KEY_AGE = "Age";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String KEY_GENDER = "Gender";
    private static final String KEY_HEIGHT = "Height";
    private static final String KEY_CURRENT_WEIGHT = "Current_Weight";
    private static final String KEY_START_WEIGHT = "Start_Weight";
    private static final String KEY_WEIGHT_CHANGE = "Weight_Change";
    private static final String KEY_BMI = "BMI";
    private static final String KEY_BMR = "BMR";
    private static final String KEY_REQ_CAL = "Required_Calories";
    private static final String KEY_MON_CAL = "Monday_Calories";
    private static final String KEY_TUES_CAL = "Tuesday_Calories";
    private static final String KEY_WED_CAL = "Wednesday_Calories";
    private static final String KEY_THUR_CAL = "Thursday_Calories";
    private static final String KEY_FRI_CAL = "Friday_Calories";
    private static final String KEY_SAT_CAL = "Saturday_Calories";
    private static final String KEY_SUN_CAL = "Sunday_Calories";
    //PRODUCT TABLE
    private static final String KEY_ITEMNAME = "Item_name";
    private static final String KEY_ITEMCALORIES = "Item_Calories";
    //
    private static final String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "( "
            + KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_AGE + " INTEGER, "
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_GENDER + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_HEIGHT + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_START_WEIGHT + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_CURRENT_WEIGHT + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_WEIGHT_CHANGE + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_BMI + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_BMR + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_REQ_CAL + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_MON_CAL + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_TUES_CAL + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_WED_CAL + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_THUR_CAL + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_FRI_CAL + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_SAT_CAL + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_SUN_CAL + " DOUBLE ); ";

    private static final String CREATE_PRODUCT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "( " + KEY_PRODUCT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_ITEMNAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_ITEMCALORIES + " DOUBLE );";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCT_TABLE);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG,
                "Upgrading the database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
        DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF IT EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF IT EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    //CRUD OPERATIONS

    public Users getUser(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS,
                new String[]{KEY_USER_ID, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD, KEY_AGE,
                        KEY_EMAIL, KEY_GENDER, KEY_HEIGHT, KEY_START_WEIGHT,
                        KEY_CURRENT_WEIGHT, KEY_WEIGHT_CHANGE, KEY_BMI, KEY_BMR,
                        KEY_REQ_CAL, KEY_MON_CAL, KEY_TUES_CAL, KEY_WED_CAL,
                        KEY_THUR_CAL, KEY_FRI_CAL, KEY_SAT_CAL, KEY_SUN_CAL},
                KEY_USER_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Users users = new Users(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2), cursor.getInt(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),
                cursor.getDouble(6), cursor.getDouble(7), cursor.getDouble(8), cursor.getDouble(9),
                cursor.getDouble(10), cursor.getDouble(11), cursor.getDouble(12), cursor.getDouble(13),
                cursor.getDouble(14), cursor.getDouble(15), cursor.getDouble(16), cursor.getDouble(17), cursor.getDouble(18), cursor.getDouble(19));
        cursor.close();
        return users;

    }

    public void addUser(Users users) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_USERNAME, users.get_username());
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, users.get_password());
        values.put(KEY_AGE, users.get_age());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, users.get_email());
        values.put(KEY_GENDER, users.get_gender());
        values.put(KEY_HEIGHT, users.get_height());
        values.put(KEY_START_WEIGHT, users.get_startWeight());
        values.put(KEY_CURRENT_WEIGHT, users.get_currentWeight());
        values.put(KEY_WEIGHT_CHANGE, users.get_weightChange());
        values.put(KEY_BMI, users.get_BMI());
        values.put(KEY_BMR, users.get_BMR());
        values.put(KEY_REQ_CAL, users.get_reqCal());
        values.put(KEY_MON_CAL, users.get_monCal());
        values.put(KEY_TUES_CAL, users.get_tuesCal());
        values.put(KEY_WED_CAL, users.get_wedCal());
        values.put(KEY_THUR_CAL, users.get_thurCal());
        values.put(KEY_FRI_CAL, users.get_friCal());
        values.put(KEY_SAT_CAL, users.get_satCal());
        values.put(KEY_SUN_CAL, users.get_sunCal());

        db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public int getUserCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        return count;

    }

    public int updateUser(Users users) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_USERNAME, users.get_username());
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, users.get_password());
        values.put(KEY_AGE, users.get_age());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, users.get_email());
        values.put(KEY_GENDER, users.get_gender());
        values.put(KEY_HEIGHT, users.get_height());
        values.put(KEY_START_WEIGHT, users.get_startWeight());
        values.put(KEY_CURRENT_WEIGHT, users.get_currentWeight());
        values.put(KEY_WEIGHT_CHANGE, users.get_weightChange());
        values.put(KEY_BMI, users.get_BMI());
        values.put(KEY_BMR, users.get_BMR());
        values.put(KEY_REQ_CAL, users.get_reqCal());
        values.put(KEY_MON_CAL, users.get_monCal());
        values.put(KEY_TUES_CAL, users.get_tuesCal());
        values.put(KEY_WED_CAL, users.get_wedCal());
        values.put(KEY_THUR_CAL, users.get_thurCal());
        values.put(KEY_FRI_CAL, users.get_friCal());
        values.put(KEY_SAT_CAL, users.get_satCal());
        values.put(KEY_SUN_CAL, users.get_sunCal());

        return db.update(TABLE_USERS, values, KEY_USER_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(users.get_id())});
    }

    public List<Users> getallUsers() {
        List<Users> usersList = new ArrayList<Users>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Users users = new Users();
                users.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                users.set_username(cursor.getString(1));
                users.set_password(cursor.getString(2));
                users.set_age(cursor.getInt(3));
                users.set_email(cursor.getString(4));
                users.set_gender(cursor.getString(5));
                users.set_height(cursor.getDouble(6));
                users.set_startWeight(cursor.getDouble(7));
                users.set_currentWeight(cursor.getDouble(8));
                users.set_weightChange();
                users.set_BMI(cursor.getDouble(10));
                users.set_BMR(cursor.getDouble(11));
                users.set_reqCal(cursor.getDouble(12));
                users.set_monCal(cursor.getDouble(13));
                users.set_tuesCal(cursor.getDouble(14));
                users.set_wedCal(cursor.getDouble(15));
                users.set_thurCal(cursor.getDouble(16));
                users.set_friCal(cursor.getDouble(17));
                users.set_satCal(cursor.getDouble(18));
                users.set_sunCal(cursor.getDouble(19));
                usersList.add(users);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return usersList;
       }




 public List<Products> getallProducts(){
    ArrayList<Products> productList = new ArrayList<Products>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Products products = new Products();
            products.set_id(cursor.getInt(0));
            products.set_itemName(cursor.getString(1));
            products.set_itemCalorie(cursor.getDouble(2));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return productList;

}

public void addProduct(Products products){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ITEMNAME, products.get_itemName());
    values.put(KEY_ITEMCALORIES, products.get_itemCalorie());

    db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}
public int getProductCount(){
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope product list is inserted in the table.But You miss to add the product to the list

```
public List<Products> getallProducts() {
        ArrayList<Products> productList = new ArrayList<Products>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Products products = new Products();
                products.set_id(cursor.getInt(0));
                products.set_itemName(cursor.getString(1));
                products.set_itemCalorie(cursor.getDouble(2));
```

> productList.add(products);

```
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return productList;

    }
```

Comment: That was the problem forgot that line, thank you for your help